# How to install php on windows 8.1 64-bit?

Tags: php, html, installation

After studying html, css and Javascipt i have decided to study php.

But when i tried to do the first hello world example i found that its not working

```
<?php 
echo "hello World";
?>
```

it shows like this:

[image: not working]

After exploring a lot i found that i need to install php before studying it.

I explore a lot and couldn't find any sutable php for my windows 8.1 (64-bit).

I even installed xampp.

But failure

Please some one provide me link to download php for  windows 8.1 (64-bit) and please guide me how can to install php and run it.

Comment: You're probably going to be much better off running it in a virtual machine

Comment: Download PHP from the official website here: http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: @GordonM Why use a virtual machine? PHP runs fine on Windows.

Comment: @Jocelyn In my experience it runs on Windows, but it would be generous to say it runs fine.  As the vast majority of hosting environments that support PHP are also Linux-based, having a Linux VM would give a development environment that's more representative of the system to which the codebase will ultimately be deployed anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install Xampp on your windows
- Open control panel of xampp
- Run apache and Mysql
- Inside the folder `htdocs` in `C:\xampp` create a new folder for your php work
- Create `Index.php` file as the main file
- Go to your favorite browser and search `localhost/`after the slash add your folders name so that you can go to that folder

Answer (score 4):

- You should put your php files in c:/xampp/htdocs folder.
- Then open your xampp control panel.
- start apache and mysql application.
- then open your browser goto http://localhost/yourphpfile.php.

  Then you will get the output. 
  I think you should be following a good tutorial to learn php though.

Comment: Hey man. have you installed xampp? Where is the install location of xampp.? do you get the xampp controll panel ? what is the output in browser

Comment: Is there any other way??